# Recursive HTML Divs in handlerbars.js templates

Tags: html, css, recursion, handlebars.js

I'm trying to figure out how to create recursive units strictly out of divs.

The root template would be (1). The (2) diagram is the expansion of the red rectangle in (1).

How would it be possible to accomplish this using html/css and no bootstrap? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you first tell us what you are recursing? The dom element itself? The style of the elements? Or both? And for any recursion, there has to be some terminal condition, or you would literally get a "stack overflow". So what is your terminal condition? Is it a certain depth?

Comment: Also, are you trying to avoid javascript? Note that HTML elements by themselves are static--you only get what you manually declare in code. They cannot modify themselves or add more elements without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
<div>
    <div id="first" class="main">
        <div class="box small"></div>
        <div class="box small"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="box large"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="second" class="main">
        <div class="box large"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="box small"></div>
        <div class="box small"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.main{height: auto; margin-bottom:40px;}
#first{border:1px solid #000; }
#second{border:1px solid red;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.box{margin: 10px; min-height: 50px;}
.small{width:48%; float:left; border:1px solid #000;}
.large{width:98%; border:1px solid red;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @naveed-ramzan. This doesn't seem to work: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM0EGBZR5XPM

Comment: Well I drafted to give you an idea. Still I updated, and you can try your self to improve. :)